# Open Source Jar file and Failed to load Main-Class manifest

Tags: java

I downloaded an Open Source tool from www.openempi.org used to find duplicate patients. It is referred to as an EMPI tool (Enterprise Master Patient Index). I am a .Net programmer and not a Java programmer, but I have worked with other Java products where I receive a Jar file and run it like a Windows executable.

The zip file contained several Jar files but when I double-click on them I get Failed to load Main-Class manifest from.... After I Googled this term and reading a few posts about it, including several on this site, this seems to indicate that I should have done something different when creating the Jar file, but I didn't create the Jar file. Will I need to use Eclipse or some other tool to get past this, or is there something I'm doing wrong when try to load the Jar? Could it be a Java version issue?

The zip also contained a ./conf folder with several XML, CSV, and SQL files.

Greg

Comment: run it in a command line interface: `java -jar myJar.jar`

Comment: Tried it in a batch file and get the same message.

Comment: Not every jar file is executable. In fact, executable jars are fairly rare. The exception you're getting means that those jars are not executable (missing the manifest information which tells java which class to run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to execute the .jars found in that .zip file. Instead, you should try using the Application.html found after extracting from the openempi-webapp-web-versionhere.war.